# Parallel updating RGBW LED strip; fast memory shuffle (with inline assembler?)

Tags: assembly, arduino, inline-assembly

I am trying to parallel update four RGBW LED strips with an Arduino Nano.
The strips are wired to digital pins 0-3 which equals bit 0-3 of I/O register PORTD. [(Image: LEDs wired to Arduino)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ridt.png)

The strip type is SK6812 RGBW but i don't think this is a very important information. [(Datasheet)](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2757/p2757_SK6812RGBW_REV01.pdf)

The important thing is that in order to update one LED you need to give it 32 bit of data in quick succession as described in the datasheet.
I've managed to do that by preparing an array of 32 bits ( named LED[32] ) which hold the information for one LED of each strip. Than load these values in I/O register PORTD to drive the pins high and low.
The LED[32] array looks like this:

(From LSB to MSB order:
w (white)
b (blue)
r (red)
g (green)

pins 4-7 were saved at the beginning and will be loaded in every frame (X) to keep them as they were)

```html
<table border="1" <tr>
  <td>bit7          </td>
  <td>bit6          </td>
  <td>bit5          </td>
  <td>bit4          </td>
  <td>bit3          </td>
  <td>bit2          </td>
  <td>bit1          </td>
  <td>bit0          </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>W3_0</td>
    <td>W2_0</td>
    <td>W1_0</td>
    <td>W0_0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>W3_1</td>
    <td>W2_1</td>
    <td>W1_1</td>
    <td>W0_1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>W3_2</td>
    <td>W2_2</td>
    <td>W1_2</td>
    <td>W0_2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>W3_3</td>
    <td>W2_3</td>
    <td>W1_3</td>
    <td>W0_3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>r3_4</td>
    <td>r2_4</td>
    <td>r1_4</td>
    <td>r0_4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>r3_5</td>
    <td>r2_5</td>
    <td>r1_5</td>
    <td>r0_5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>r3_6</td>
    <td>r2_6</td>
    <td>r1_6</td>
    <td>r0_6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>r3_7</td>
    <td>r2_7</td>
    <td>r1_7</td>
    <td>r0_7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This information needs to be calculated prior to the writing process of an LED.
The time between two writing processes must be less than 80uS!
For the 16 MHz Arduino that is 1280 cycles.

At this point my calculation is not fast enough.

The information of the LEDs is stored in an array named LEDs["Number of LEDs"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3rxj.jpg)[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3rxj.jpg)
One dimension of the array for each LED, the second one for the four colors, and the last one for the four different strips.

My code to write to all LEDs:

```
static inline __attribute__ ((always_inline)) void showPixel() {
  // Send the 32 Bits down every row. Remember that each pixel is 32 bits wide (8 bits each for R,G, B & W)
  uint8_t bit;
  uint8_t onPixel,offPixel; //output of PORTD when high or low is being written
  cli(); //no interrupts
  offPixel = PIXEL_PORT;  //safe output of Port D
  offPixel &= 0xf0; //create Bitmask for setting bit 4-7 of Port D to original value and leds off 0bxxxx0000
  onPixel = offPixel | 0x0f;  //led pins high plus IO pins as they were 0bxxxx1111
  
  for(uint8_t ledNr=0; ledNr < NUM_LEDS; ledNr++)  {
    
    shuffle(0,LEDs[ledNr][3][0],LEDs[ledNr][3][1],LEDs[ledNr][3][2],LEDs[ledNr][3][3],offPixel);//white
    shuffle(8,LEDs[ledNr][2][0],LEDs[ledNr][2][1],LEDs[ledNr][2][2],LEDs[ledNr][2][3],offPixel);//blue
    shuffle(16,LEDs[ledNr][0][0],LEDs[ledNr][0][1],LEDs[ledNr][0][2],LEDs[ledNr][0][3],offPixel);//red
    shuffle(24,LEDs[ledNr][1][0],LEDs[ledNr][1][1],LEDs[ledNr][1][2],LEDs[ledNr][1][3],offPixel);//green
    
  
    bit=32; 
    while (bit--) { //send out the 32 bytes
      sendBitX4_lower( LED[bit] ,onPixel,offPixel); 
    }
  }
  sei(); //activate interrupts
}
```

My shuffle function:

```
static inline  __attribute__ ((always_inline)) void shuffle(uint8_t bit, uint8_t v0, uint8_t v1,uint8_t v2, uint8_t v3,uint8_t IOpins){
  uint8_t  res,pos,mask=8;
  pos=bit+8;
    //LED[bit]=0; EDIT: this was a test
    //LED[bit++]=0; to see if decreasing the resolution
    //LED[bit++]=0; speeds it up enough to work
    //bit++;        at 5 bit resolution it was barely fast enough
  while(bit<pos){
    if(v3 & mask) res=8;
    else res=0;
    if(v2 & mask) res|=4;
    if(v1 & mask) res|=2;
    if(v0 & mask) res|=1;
    mask<<=1;
    res|=IOpins;      //Set bits 0-3 to the output that was present
    LED[bit]=res;
    bit++;
  }
```

It can be a bit hard to understand what needs to be done in the suffle function. I've tried to draw it so maybe you can understand it easier [(attachment shuffle.pdf)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0R3S.png).
Essentially the calculation is split up in 4 parts for each color. Each shuffle will write to 8 bytes of the LED[32] array. This process looks a bit like a matrix that is being inverted. Each byte of the LED[32] has elements of 4 different bytes of the LEDs array. Starting with the LSB for LED[0] and moving up to the MSB for LED[8] and so on.

I've tried different examples of this. Some with bit shifting, some with pointers going through the arrays, but this was the fastest.

My question is: is it physically possible to do this calculation in this many cycles? And if yes, how?
Probably with inline assembler but i'm just getting into that...
Thanks for your help. If your interested we could refine this and make it accessible to everyone :)

Update:
I don't think it is possible to get around the shuffle, because the timing of output of 32 bit information per LED is critical. In my code the sendBitX4_lower() function is called 32 times to do that.
The time for sending one bit of information is 1.25µs±600ns lets say 1.9µs that is 30 cycles at max.

If you are interested this is the code:

```
static inline __attribute__ ((always_inline)) void sendBitX4_lower( uint8_t bits ,uint8_t onBits,uint8_t offBits ) {
    asm volatile (
      "out %[port], %[onBits] \n\t"           // 1st step - send T0H high 

      ".rept %[T0HCycles] \n\t"               // Execute NOPs to delay exactly the specified number of cycles
        "nop \n\t"
      ".endr \n\t"

      "out %[port], %[bits] \n\t"             // set the output bits to thier values for T0H-T1H
      ".rept %[dataCycles] \n\t"               // Execute NOPs to delay exactly the specified number of cycles
      "nop \n\t"
      ".endr \n\t"

      "out %[port],%[offBits]  \n\t"        // last step - T1L all bits low

      // Don't need an explicit delay here since the overhead that follows will always be long enough
      ::
      [port]    "I" (_SFR_IO_ADDR(PIXEL_PORT)),
      [bits]   "d" (bits),
      [onBits]   "d" (onBits),
      [offBits]  "d" (offBits),
      [T0HCycles]  "I" (NS_TO_CYCLES(T0H) - 2),           // 1-bit width less overhead  for the actual bit setting, note that this delay could be longer and everything would still work
      [dataCycles]   "I" (NS_TO_CYCLES((T1H-T0H)) - 2)// Minimum interbit delay. Note that we probably don't need this at all since the loop overhead will be enough, but here for correctness
    );
    // Note that the inter-bit gap can be as long as you want as long as it doesn't exceed the reset timeout (which is A long time)
}
```

I guess a bit of time each frame could be used to do a part of the calculation but doubt all of it. That would be 960 cycles. It might work because the memory saving part is now unnecessary but on the other hand the writing to the port needs to be done.
So all calculation for one frame would need to find time in this sequence:[Timing Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3rxj.jpg) That would involve load from RAM as well as four "if"s that would probably result in a conditional jump (sbrc 1-2 cycles). 
I've had a look at the library from Adafruit (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel) to get inspiration.

Comment: Why do you send first Wx_0 (according to that HTML table), when the datasheet says *"order to send data (R7 - R6 - ... W0)"*? Am I misunderstanding something?  .... and *"From LSB to MSB order: w (white) b (blue) r (red) g (green)"* - really exotic WBRG, or is it just typo and you have more common WBGR or WRGB?

Comment: And what is `sendBitX4_lower`? Why do you shuffle it in the memory and then output the shuffled data, when you can simply just output it immediately without writing the shuffled values into memory. IMO that write is costing you a lot. Anyway, 1280 cycles sounds like ages available (mind you, on ZX Spectrum you had 70000 cycles for 1 display frame (yes, that's only 70k), and each instruction did cost 4 to 23 cycles, not even 1), do you have optimizations ON when compiling that C? .. EDIT: oh, it's `LED` vs `LEDs` .. :/

Comment: And finally, in `shuffle`: why you set first two bits to zero `LED[bit]=0;` (overwriting the first bit twice by following `LED[bit++]=0;`), and then skip third bit completely by `bit++;` without setting it, then you set the remaining 5 bits from the colour values... weird. Why not full 8 bits of each colour?  - What CPU has your Arduino?

Comment: @Ped7g I´m sorry that's my fault. This is not exactly the code i wanted to post. The one you see at the moment is "speed up" by reducing the resolution. This was an experiment to see at what point the strip would work. It works (is fast enough) if only 5 bits are "shuffled" so i get a resolution of 2^5=32. So the original code has these 4 lines removed.

Comment: The array LED ist send out from 32 going down without specific reason.
So white is actually send at the very end. I also noticed the difference of the datasheet and my chip. With my chip the order of red and green seem to be swapped.

Comment: The Arduino is using an ATmega328 processor. With this instructions as far as i know 
http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-0856-AVR-Instruction-Set-Manual.pdf

Comment: @Ped7g: [Arduino Nano](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-nano) is an AVR (8-bit RISC) microcontroller with 2k of SRAM.  Most instructions are 1 clock, branches are 2 if jumping.  Stores are apparently only 2 cycles ([HTML ISA reference entry for `ST`](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_STD.html).  (That's for the internal SRAM built-in to the CPU, I think.)  But setting up the index register is probably as expensive as the actual load/store.  http://gcc.godbolt.org/ has AVR gcc installed.

Comment: @MilesDelwig: It's pretty hard to follow exactly what pattern of data you have, and what you need.  You seem to be storing your data in 1 bit per byte, but your output device needs it in 4 bits per nibble.   So why can't you store your patterns already packed, and use shifts or rotates instead of extracting bits from multiple bytes every time?  It's hard to see how much of your complexity is necessary and how much could go away with a different choice of storage format.  IDK if you could clean up the question to make that easier to see, separate from your current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

How about (a blind try, as I don't have arduino IDE, neither did I try to compile with any C compiler, so you may need to fix syntax maybe):

```c
static void showPixel() {
    const uint8_t colorOffsets[4] = { 1, 0, 2, 3 };     // move somewhere into constants?
    ... set up "offPixel" here
    cli(); //no interrupts
    for(uint8_t ledNr=0; ledNr < NUM_LEDS; ++ledNr)  {
        for (uint8_t colorIdx = 0; colorIdx < 4; ++colorIdx) {
            const uint8_t* v_ptr = LEDs[ledNr][colorOffsets[colorIdx]];
            uint8_t bitMask = 0x80;
            do {
                uint8_t toSend = offPixel;  // upper 4 bits preserved PORTD, lower 4 bits cleared
                // set lower 4 bits by the colour values
                if (v_ptr[0] & bitMask) toSend |= 1;
                if (v_ptr[1] & bitMask) toSend |= 2;
                if (v_ptr[2] & bitMask) toSend |= 4;
                if (v_ptr[3] & bitMask) toSend |= 8;

                //TODO send "toSend" to PORTD
                ???
                PIXEL_PORT = toSend;  // guessing it

                bitMask >>= 1;              // next bit of values
            } while (bitMask); // all 8 bits of color value
        }
    }
    sei(); //activate interrupts
}
```

And I wouldn't inline that one, why? It sends data over all LEDs, sounds like big-enough unit to have it just once in code memory.

It should scan Green, Red, Blue, White from top bit for each stripe, build the byte to be sent to PORTD (pins 0-3 from LEDs data, pines 4-7 kept from `offPixel`). And then you should just send it. No shuffling in memory, reading the correct bits in the pattern in which they should be emitted.

Also it does send full 8 bits of colour, if you want to set certain bits to zero by force, you can probably change `while (bitMask)` to some particular bit test, and then emit `offPixel` value remaining times to emit 8 bits in total.

---

EDIT:

I tried this source for a while in [godbolt set to AVR gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/FUcC85), and I have these observations...

First the inner source used (full source on godbolt link above. I was not sure how Arduino defines PORTD, so I put there some volatile memory absolute address, should be close enough):

```c
for(uint8_t ledNr=0; ledNr < NUM_LEDS; ++ledNr)  {
    for (uint8_t colorIdx = 0; colorIdx < 4; ++colorIdx) {
        const uint8_t* v_ptr = LEDs[ledNr][colorOffsets[colorIdx]];
        const uint8_t v0 = v_ptr[0];
        const uint8_t v1 = v_ptr[1];
        const uint8_t v2 = v_ptr[2];
        const uint8_t v3 = v_ptr[3];
        uint8_t bitMask = 0x80;
        do {
            PIXEL_PORT = offPixel;      // set the LED bits to low
            asm volatile("": : :"memory");
            // uint8_t toSend = offPixel;  // upper 4 bits preserved PORTD, lower 4 bits cleared
            // // set lower 4 bits by the colour values
            // if (v0 & bitMask) toSend |= 1;
            uint8_t toSend = offPixel | ((v0 & bitMask) ? 1 : 0);
            if (v1 & bitMask) toSend |= 2;
            if (v2 & bitMask) toSend |= 4;
            if (v3 & bitMask) toSend |= 8;

            PIXEL_PORT = toSend;        // set the LED bits to high
            asm volatile("": : :"memory");

            bitMask >>= 1;              // next bit of values
        } while (bitMask); // all 8 bits of color value
    } //for (uint8_t colorIdx = 0; colorIdx < 4; ++colorIdx) {
} //for(uint8_t ledNr=0; ledNr < NUM_LEDS; ++ledNr)
```

The resulting assembly looks like a possible base to work upon, it unrolls the loop 8 times (for `bitMask`) and turns the `bitMask` test into specific `sbrc + ori` pairs, which makes sense to me. The problem is, that the off+on bit set on port will be too short (it switches bits ON and then immediately starts next bit by switching them OFF in the next instruction, and there's not much to do to slow it down, except adding `nop` delay loop).

And the major problem is, that to get fixed timing across all 32 LEDs, you would need to have to prepare the initial state ahead of unrolled loop, and keep preparing next state toward end of the 7/8th bit test in the delays, so the next LED would start in fixed time just like next bit does.

The C output directly doesn't look to be usable, but may be reasonable template for your own unrolled loop (if you are good enough in assembly, I don't want to write full `showPixels()` routine, because I never did AVR assembly, plus I don't know how reading/writing to port should be done, plus it's quite tedious to write unrolled loops of this size.

The core code (commented by me) (in this part the 4th bit is tested, i.e. `bitMask == 0x10`):

```
    out 52-0x20,r20    // PORTD = offPixel
    ldi r23,lo8(1)
    sbrs r24,4         // 4th bit (the number goes from 7 to 0)
    ldi r23,lo8(0)     // toSend = 0/1 (? (v0 & bitMask))
    or r23,r20         // toSend |= offPixel
    sbrc r25,4
    ori r23,lo8(2)     // if (v1 & bitMask) toSend |= 2
    sbrc r21,4
    ori r23,lo8(4)     // if (v2 & bitMask) toSend |= 4
    sbrc r22,4
    ori r23,lo8(8)     // if (v3 & bitMask) toSend |= 8
    out 52-0x20,r23    // PORTD = toSend
```

I would write by hand the initial part in the same way as the remaining bit tests, i.e. (makes it much easier for reading by human to have all bits handled by the same fashion code):

```
    out 52-0x20,r20    //1c // PORTD = offPixel
    mov r23,r20        //1c // toSend = offPixel
    sbrc r24,4         //1/2c // 4th bit (the number goes from 7 to 0)
    ori r23,lo8(1)     //1c // if (v0 & bitMask) toSend |= 1
    sbrc r25,4         //1/2c
    ori r23,lo8(2)     //1c // if (v1 & bitMask) toSend |= 2
    sbrc r21,4         //1/2c
    ori r23,lo8(4)     //1c // if (v2 & bitMask) toSend |= 4
    sbrc r22,4         //1/2c
    ori r23,lo8(8)     //1c // if (v3 & bitMask) toSend |= 8
    out 52-0x20,r23    //1c // PORTD = toSend
```

(I tried to modify C to suggest that, but the gcc instead inserts two branching `rjmp` to load the register directly with either `offPixel` or `offPixel+1` value, annoying...)

The `sbrc + ori` pairs will take fixed 2 clocks for both skip/set condition, so after the `offPixel` is written to the port, it will take exactly 10 clock cycles to write ON state. That looks to be slightly off the accepted range, if I'm reading your timing overview correctly. So you can move the OFF out somewhere later, like ahead of second `sbrc`, that will make it 7 clocks between OFF and ON `out`. (actually hand holding gcc on godbolt works: https://godbolt.org/g/V2vf2X )

Then you have 4+12 for the next loop... that new beginning part (up till second `sbrc` is already eating 4c, and you have 12c to fill up by housekeeping or artificial delay.

And toward end (bits 2, 1, 0 ...) in the housekeeping/delay part you need to fetch new LED values into `v0/v1/v2/v3` registers, for simplicity I would probably use two ranges of registers like `r18+` for first pass, `r26+` for second pass and do 16 times loop of the two (may need careful register usage design to fit within available spare registers).

Thinking about it, the load of `vX` values for stripes can also move ahead the pointer, i.e. `ldd rX,Z+`, that's about 2 cycles (I'm not sure which clocks to apply, on XMEGA not accessing SRAM you can be 1 cycle, but I think you are accessing SRAM with that `LEDs`?), i.e. 4x2 = 8 cycles. That can wholly fit into 12c delay with spare cycles to adjust `Z` (going from green [1] to red [0] and from red [0] to blue [2], i.e. `sub v_ptr,8` in first case and `add v_ptr,4` in second, and then the `Z` should already point to white [3] after blue [2] is finished. Also if you have `LEDs` aligned well, you can `sub/add` just the low part of `Z`).

So the total code architecture would be like:

- prepare pointer `ledptr` into `LEDs[0][1]` (`Z` reg)
- cli()
- read `offPixel` (fixed reg for whole code)
- { // loop 32 times this
- 2c `Y` = pointer into nextColorPtr table `{ -8, +4, +0, +0 }`
- { // loop 4 times this

  - 8c read v0, v1, v2, v3 with `Z+`
  - 1c toSend = offPixel
  - 2c if (v0 & 0x80) toSend |= 1
  - 1c PORTD = offPixel   // OFF state send here (after 14c)
  - 6c 3x if (v1/2/3 & 0x80) toSend |= 2/4/8
  - 1c PORTD = toSend     // ON state send here (after 7c)
  - ~4-8c `Z += [Y+]` (add -8/+4/0/0 to `Z` from table at `Y`) (too lazy to try on my own to see what exact clocks that will be) (also depends whether you have `LEDs` aligned, so it's enough to adjust lower `Z` part, or you need to do proper 16b `add` to whole `Z`).
  - ~8-4c artificial `nop` delay to fill up remaining time to 12c total
  - // second bit starts here
  - 1c toSend = offPixel
  - 2c if (v0 & 0x40) toSend |= 1
  - 1c PORTD = offPixel   // OFF state send here (after 16c since ON state)
  - 6c 3x if (v1/2/3 & 0x40) toSend |= 2/4/8
  - 1c PORTD = toSend     // ON state send here (after 7c)
  - 12c `nop` delay
  - // third bit starts here
  - 1c toSend = offPixel
  - 2c if (v0 & 0x20) toSend |= 1
  - 1c PORTD = offPixel   // OFF state send here (after 16c since ON state)
  - 6c 3x if (v1/2/3 & 0x20) toSend |= 2/4/8
  - 1c PORTD = toSend     // ON state send here (after 7c)
  - 12c `nop` delay
  - ...
  - test if Y points beyond `nextColorPtr` and if this is last from main 32 loops and have branch into 3 variants of last bit code, one variant is loop to "// loop 4 times" continuing (must delay plus branch to loop in 4c to have 16c total till OFF state), second variant is looping back to "// loop 32 times" to proceed next LED, must be done in 2c to have total 16c till OFF state (i.e. just branch == 2c), third variant is to continue toward exit of the procedure (32 LEDs were processed), start each variant by `nop` delay filling it up to 12c total
  - // example of last bit variant for valid Y
  - // last bit starts here
  - 1c toSend = offPixel
  - 2c if (v0 & 0x01) toSend |= 1
  - 1c PORTD = offPixel   // OFF state send here (after 16c since ON state)
  - 6c 3x if (v1/2/3 & 0x01) toSend |= 2/4/8
  - 1c PORTD = toSend     // ON state send here (after 7c)
  - 2c `nop` `nop`
  - 2c branch to // loop 4 times

...

- // example of last bit variant for invalid Y, but valid Z pointer (or counter < 32)
- // last bit starts here
- 1c toSend = offPixel
- 2c if (v0 & 0x01) toSend |= 1
- 1c PORTD = offPixel   // OFF state send here (after 16c since ON state)
- 6c 3x if (v1/2/3 & 0x01) toSend |= 2/4/8
- 1c PORTD = toSend     // ON state send here (after 7c)
- 2c branch to // loop 32 times

I'm not going to try to write inline ASM for gcc, because I'm completely lost at specifying the clobbered registers/etc.. i.e. making it valid gcc inline. Plus this took me way more time than I expected. (If I would do this for myself, I would write it rather in stand-alone assembly)

But it looks doable, if I understood your timing drawing correctly. So-so, but doable for 4 strips. If you would need more than 4 strips, there's still some delaying here and there to bump it probably to 8 strips at max, but that would require to unroll/interleave the start/end of loops much more aggressively, over several bits (for 8 strips it would probably need to interleave the housekeeping over whole 8 bits code, i.e. no copy/paste at all, each delay formed by tiny piece of next-LED preparation code, and it would need 2 sets of working regs).

If I didn't overlook anything, this should produce fixed 7 clock of OFF state with 16 clocks of ON state (23 clocks total between two bits) for whole 32 LEDs x 4 colors (128 bytes send to port).

The currently suggested source will be already well over 100 lines of code, very tedious to write, debug and maintain, but as you need fixed timing, looks like most reasonable approach.

Comment: I've quickly implemented your code with minor adjustments. The bits need to be set low at first and after a specific time to their value than to zero. I've added an timing overview to my question were this is visualized. Without further refining all LEDs show at least some response!! That shows that calculating it immediately rater than storing it could be the way to go! 
I will try to tune the timing a bit and see how good it gets. Thanks

Comment: @MilesDelwig the timing looks really tight. You can basically write offPixel to the port at the beginning of the bitmask `do {} while` loop, but then you need to verify the inner fetch data + if () or execute in constant time and fast enough, to replace the timing `nops` with the inner loop code instead. But if you have like 7+4+12 cycles available only, then it may be impossible for 4 strips at the same time (let's say: port=off 1c, 4x[fetch 2c, if+or 2c] port=on 1c, shift 1c, loop 2c = 21c of 23c in total ... and you need to raise the port somewhere in middle, not end of `while` loop.

Comment: looks to me like 2 strips would be almost possible (with hand tuned assembly), can't you update rather 2+2 interleaved? Or even single strip and loop 4 times. We are still in microseconds per single strip, so the delayed update will be probably invisible to humans, unless some perfect horizontal scroll is happening in the image data. But if the total time is under 5ms, it may be not noticeable, or just very mild "italic" effect. Other option is to prepare whole bitmap with desired bit patterns, so you can output it directly (each byte containing 2x low 4bits to be outputted).